# Why am i getting this run time error in lua of bad argument #-1 to '_newindex' (string expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I was configuring the transparency in my rc.lua file for my awesome wm. I am now getting the error mentioned in the title. I have since opened up my original rc.lua thats located in /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua and made it exactly the same, yet i still get this error. Any thoughts?

```
client.connect_signal("focus", function(c) c.border_color = beautiful.border_focus end)
client.connect_signal("unfocus", function(c) c.border_color = beautiful.border_normal end)
```

Comment: You changed the system file to look like your modified file that was causing the problem? Or you changed your local file to look like the system file? Are you sure those are the lines causing the problem?

Comment: No I used the system file as a reference for my modified file when I started getting the error.  When I restart awesome the error is to the path of my modified file along with the number of line references which points to these two lines of code

Comment: If you comment those lines out does the error go away or move? Nothing about those lines looks like it can be causing that error (though metatable magic could be involved and cause it).

Comment: yeah, the errors do go away. But them i am left with a black screen with only the wibox up the top with the virtual displays i have edited.

Comment: Sounds like you may have more serious issues with your configuration file then perhaps. How many lines is your config file? How heavily customized is it?

Comment: Ill explore the metatable in lua. When i was configuring transparency i installed xcompmgr, transset-df and devilspie. I only configured what i needed to within these programs as well as .xinitrc so that xcompmgr and devilspie would run at boot up. i have since then commented them out but to no avail. I was following this guide if it helps... 

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Per_Application_Transparency

Comment: 550 approx.. i had only configured a few things, im just new to awsome wm so i only added a widget or two and changed the names of the virtual workspaces, added a background etc.

Comment: Yeah, that guide doesn't really have you modify the awesome configuration so that's not really involved here. Unless you put the devilspie configuration into your awesome rc.lua file by accident or something.

Comment: If you started from the default configuration then I would say try seeing what `diff /path/to/system/rc.lua /home/user/path/to/rc.lua` outputs (and possibly paste or link that here if it isn't too large).

Comment: do you want to see both .lua files ?

Comment: Just the diff is probably fine for now.

Comment: --Start vicious here
vicious = require("vicious")


-- Table of layouts to cover with awful.layout.inc, order matters.
local layouts =
{
    awful.layout.suit.tile,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.left,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.top,
    awful.layout.suit.fair,
    awful.layout.suit.fair.horizontal,
    awful.layout.suit.floating
}
-- }}}

Comment: -- {{{ Tags
-- Define a tag table which hold all screen tags.
tags = {}
for s = 1, screen.count() do
    -- Each screen has its own tag table.
    tags[s] = awful.tag({ "Home", "Comms", "IRC", "M-Media", "Programming", "Hack", "VM" }, s, layouts[1])
end
-- }}}

Comment: -- Initialize widget
cpuwidget = awful.widget.graph()
-- Graph properties
cpuwidget:set_width(50)
cpuwidget:set_background_color("#000000")
cpuwidget:set_color({ type = "linear", from = { 0, 0 }, to = { 10,0 }, stops = { {0, "#FF5656"}, {0.5, "#88A175"},
                    {1, "#AECF96" }}})
-- Register widget
vicious.register(cpuwidget, vicious.widgets.cpu, "$1")

Comment: Thats pretty much it, sorry about the influx of posts

Comment: it was something to do with selecting the arch theme instead of the default.

Comment: In the arch theme there is an error of E520: not allowed in modeline: encoding=utf-8. I have just pointed the rc.lua file to the default theme and customised that one instead

Comment: That's a `vim` editor error. That's not an awesome or lua error and will not affect anything about loading the file or cause the error you were getting.

Answer (score 3):

I got the Error when installing a new Theme, but I guess it could be the same problem.

The two mentioned lines are perfectly fine, the error message is misleading!! The problem was (in my configuration at least) a wrong path to my theme file:

```
# This was the original line:
# beautiful.init("~/.config/awesome/themes/Darklooks/")
# and now the working full path to my theme file:
beautiful.init("~/.config/awesome/themes/Darklooks/theme.lua")
```

Comment: I got the very same problem: wrong path to the theme, then same error message at these two innocuous lines. Thanks a lot for the answer!